# Safe approach to achieve two-way communication with TIdTCPServer and TIdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I'm building a client/server application where the clients will only communicate with one server (there is no communication between clients).

When I need to send a file from server to a client, first I send a string command to instruct the client to ask server for the file.

Considering server will only talks with one client at a given time, there is no communication between clients and I have few clients connected (less than 50), the questions are:

- Can I send a string message from server to client outside the OnExecute event?
- Is my approach safe?

**Server**

```
//==============================================================================
// Server Execute procedure
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Cmd: string;
  Date: TDateTime;
  Timestamp: string;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Cmd := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;

  Date := Now;
  Timestamp := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd_hhmmss', Date);

  if Cmd = 'send_file' then
  begin
    try
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

      try
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Stream, -1, False);

        Stream.Position := 0;

        Stream.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +
          '\recv_test' + Timestamp + '.dat');
      except on E: Exception do
        Log('Error loading file: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
      end;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end else if Cmd = 'recv_file' then
  begin
    try
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

      try
        Stream.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test.dat');
        Stream.Position := 0;

        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('send_file');
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Stream, 0, True);
      except on E: Exception do
        Log('Error sending file: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
      end;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
// Server send file button
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.btnSendFileClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  List: TList;
  ip: string;
  I: Integer;
  Context: TIdContext;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  // lvwPCList is a ListView on my form...
  // Do I need to use TThread.Queue to safety access this component?
  ip := GStack.ResolveHost(lvwPCList.Selected.Caption);

  try
    List := TCPServer.Contexts.LockList;

    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
    Context := TIdContext(List[I]);

      if Context.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP = ip then
      begin
      Context.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('send_file');

        try
          Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

          try
            Stream.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test.dat');
            Stream.Position := 0;

            Context.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Stream, 0, True);
          except on E: Exception do
            Log('Error sending file: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
          end;
        finally
          Stream.Free;
        end;

        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
//  Server get file button
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.btnGetFileClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  List: TList;
  IP: string;
  I: Integer;
  Context: TIdContext;
begin
  IP := GStack.ResolveHost(lvwPCList.Selected.Caption);

  try
    List := TCPServer.Contexts.LockList;

    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
    Context := TIdContext(List[I]);

      if Context.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP = IP then
      begin
        Context.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('recv_file');
        // After send the string command 'recv_file', the server
    // will receive the actual file sending by client on the execute event...
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
```

**Client**

```
//==============================================================================
procedure ThreadActionStart;
var
  ThreadAction: TThreadAction;
begin
  ThreadAction := TThreadAction.Create(True);
  ThreadAction.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  ThreadAction.Priority := tpNormal;
  ThreadAction.Start;
end;
//==============================================================================
procedure TThreadAction.Execute;
var
  Cmd: string;
  Date: TDateTime;
  Timestamp: string;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  while frmMain.IdTCPClient.Connected do
  begin
    try
      cmd := frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn;

    TThread.Queue( nil,
      procedure
    begin
      frmMain.lstMessages.Items.Add(cmd);
    end
    );

      Date := Now;
      Timestamp := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd_hhmmss', Date);

      if Cmd = 'send_file' then
      begin
        try
          Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

          try
            frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(Stream, -1);
            Stream.Position := 0;
            Stream.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +
              '\recv_test' + Timestamp + '.dat');
          except on E: Exception do
            Log('Error loading file: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
          end;
        finally
          Stream.Free;
        end;
      end else if Cmd = 'recv_file' then
      begin
        try
          Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

          try
            Stream.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test.dat');
            Stream.Position := 0;

            frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('send_file');
            frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(Stream, 0, True);
          except on E: Exception do
            Log('Error sending file: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
          end;
        finally
          Stream.Free;
        end;
      end;
    except
      Log('Error reading from server');
    end;
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.btnGetFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('recv_file');
end;
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.btnSendFileClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('send_file');

    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      Stream.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'test.dat');
      Stream.Position := 0;

      frmMain.IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(Stream, 0, True);
    except on E: Exception do
      Log('Error sending file: ' + E.ClassName + ' - ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
      Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    IdTCPClient.Host := '192.168.0.20';
    IdTCPClient.Port := 4545;
    IdTCPClient.Connect;
  except
    Log('Connection error');
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPClientConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    ThreadActionStart;
  except
    Log('Error - Thread not started');
  end;
end;
//==============================================================================
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say this question belongs on CodeReview, not here. But no close option for that. So instead, I'll do the same that everyone else is doing and vote to close as "too broad".

Comment: OK Jerry Dodge, I will follow your advice. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, your approach is not safe. `OnExecute` sends/receives data in reply to commands, so you cannot send/receive other data from outside of `OnExecute` at the same time. The two would overlap and corrupt the communications. You must synchronize everything so the socket is only doing one thing at a time. All of your outside-`OnExecute` logic would have to be moved into `OnExecute` with a queuing system so `OnExecute` decides when to process an inbound command vs a queued command. Or design your communication to support multiplexing instead, and use locks on socket I/O to prevent packet overlaps.

Comment: Ok @RemyLebeau, I will research the best way of doing it considering your suggestions. Thank you for the reply in so short notice.